# What Spring MVC controller to use for form with dynamic fields 

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a form where I have two fields that I can add as much as I can. Think of it as like the upload file in gmail where I can add 1,2,3... files to upload only that I have two fields.

I am not so sure how this will check out using a SimpleFormController in Spring. Will the Spring Controller bind the them automatically?

My command class looks like this:

```
public class Course {
    private long ID;
    private String Owner;
    private String Title;
    private String Learning Objective;

    //I am not so sure how this will be bound
    private List<LearningActivity> learningActivities;

    //accessor methods

}

public class LearningActivity {
   private String Description;
   private String link;

   //accessor methods 

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use **Annotation-based** Spring controllers as SimpleFormController is deprecated as of spring 3.0

> If you are using annotations based
>   controller then their is no need to
>   extend any class or implement any
>   interface. The only thing you need to
>   do to make your simple java class to
>   become a Spring controller is to add
>   the @Controller annotation to it.

Example **[here](http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-annotation-controller-1.html)**

Also for handling dynamic fields in the form, it is better  that you use **Spring Form Tags**

Example **[here](http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-form-tags-1.html)**

**Edit:** check **[5.4.2.1. Registering additional custom PropertyEditors](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/validation.html)** in spring docs, it has an example of what u want

Comment: rawr :( Unfortunately I am still using Spring 2.5.6. Is there a way to do this in Spring 2.5.6?

Comment: see http://www.vaannila.com/spring/spring-simple-form-controller-1.html for example on simpleformcontroller

Comment: Hi I saw the tutorial! It's great it answers some of my questions. There's one thing left though, I think I need I need to create a "custom property editor" because I have a custom data type (in my code above LearningActivity). 

Do you have any tutorials to do that? :)